# Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Motor Bike'

Tags: mysql, sql

Why I am getting this error when I execute this sql statement ,anybody with an idea?
THIS IS SQL

```
UPDATE sub_category SET `name`="Motor Bike" AND category_id="13" WHERE id= "3" LIMIT 1
```

THIS IS RESULT

> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Motor Bike'

Answer (score 1):

The code you want does not use `and`:

```
UPDATE sub_category
    SET name = 'Motor Bike',
        category_id = '13'
    WHERE id = 3
    LIMIT 1;
```

Your code is interpreted as:

```
SET name = ('Motor Bike' AND category_id = '13')
```

That is, the `AND` is a boolean `AND` that connects two expressions.

Comment: When you get a correct answer, accept it by clicking the big check, and upvote it.